# 500 Internal Server Error - Unable to upload large video files using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

Not able to upload large video file up to(20 to 100 MB). 
Already setup php.ini file on server .

> upload_max_filesize = 2000M
>
> post_max_size = 2000M
>
> max_execution_time = 120
>
> max_file_uploads = 7
>
> memory_limit=128M

Getting

```
"HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error The page cannot be displayed
 because an internal server error has occurred."
```

or

```
"This page is not available."
```

sometime uploading process is shows 40 to 60 percent then its automatically restart the uploading process.

using simple  **move_uploaded_file()** php function.

```
<?php 
ini_set('max_execution_time', 50000);
 $target = "upload/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
    {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']). " has been uploaded";
    } 
     else 
     {
     echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
     }
 ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: This may help you http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/

Comment: The absolute first thing you should always do when you get a 500 Internal Server error is look into the server’s log files.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience about this error (trust me was not the best times of my life) 500 Internal Server Error on file uploads usually happens when your php is configured to run as `fastcgi` . Ask your hosting provider and/or server administrator to increase (or define if it's not already defined) the size of `FcgidMaxRequestLen` aka `MaxRequestLen` parameter.

Check this page and search "500 Internal Server Error" on the page.
http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html